# How to change my script from using only US telephone number to use US and international or at least UK numbers

Tags: php, curl, twilio, twilio-php

I have a script that gathers a phone numbers and sends it out through a URL into another script.  The script works fine for US numbers but I cannot get it to work with UK numbers and I have tried to figure it out with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I am using.

```
<?php
session_start();

  function post_to_sms($url,$post_string)
  {
    // post form to SMS API

    $curl_result=$curl_err='';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

    // note - set HOST where your API resides
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_string),
            "Host: yourdomain.com",
            "Connection: close"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT , 1);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);

    // 2 lines of debug (comment for production)
//   print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
//    echo "<br /> error = " . $curl_err = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $curl_result;
  } // end of CURL function

  // URL for your SMS API
  $url = "yourdomain.com/sms/sms_controlling.php";

  if( isset($_REQUEST['telNumber']) )
  {
    if( is_numeric( $_REQUEST['telNumber'] ) && ( $_REQUEST['telNumber'] > '1000000000' ) &&  ( $_REQUEST['telNumber'] < '9999999999' ) )
    {

        // create array of form variables
        // 'From' is input - 'To' and 'Body' is hard-coded 

        $post_data['From'] = $_REQUEST['telNumber'];
        $post_data['To'] = "%2b17204447777";  //Enter Twilio Phone number
        $post_data['Body'] = "keyword Here";  //Enter The Keyword to your SMS Campaign.

        foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
        {
          $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }
        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

        post_to_sms( $url, $post_string );

    } else {
      $_SESSION['errmessage'] = "Sorry.  All 10 Digits of Phone Number (incl Area Code) are required.";
    }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you are using these if-conditions? `$_REQUEST['telNumber'] > '1000000000' ` and `$_REQUEST['telNumber'] < '9999999999'`

Comment: For international numbers you need to ensure you're using the country code prefix (in the UK that is +44). Are you doing that? Is that messing with the conditions Titanoboa has asked about?

Comment: Hi, I'm not a programmer and this is the only way I could figure out how to get it to work in the US.  I change the %2b1 to +44 and it sends the information correctly but when my application receives the url string it will not send it to twilio. So it must lie within my application and not the the form.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

As philnash has pointed out, UK numbers start 44. Depending on the interface you are using you might need to simply set the number prefix to 44, +44 or you might need to set the Number Plan Indicator. The + commonly preceding international numbers is a shortcut for mobile devices to set the NPI and does not normally have any relevance in messaging protocols otherwise... so you will need to consult with your SMS provider.